# acceptLabel, acceptVisible in PrimeNG ConfirmDialog are not working

Tags: angular, primeng

I was trying to customize the PrimeNG [ConfirmDialog](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/confirmdialog) from within the component.ts in my Angular application but the `acceptLable`, `acceptVisible` properties are not working. The `icon`, `header`, `message`, `accept()`, `reject()` etc all are working properly. Any clue for this ?

**PrimeNG version: 4.1.1**

Below are the codes:

**component.html:**

```
<p-confirmDialog closable="false" #cd>
    <p-footer>
        <button type="button" (click)="cd.accept()"></button>
        <button type="button" (click)="cd.reject()"></button>
    <p-footer>
</p-confirmDialog>
```

**component.ts:**

```
import {ConfirmationService} from 'primeng/primeng';

@Component({
    ..
    providers: [ConfirmationService]
})

constructor(private confirmService: ConfirmationService){
    this.notAllowedToLeave = true;    /* Based upon this variable the confirmation dialog will display the Accept button i.e. "Yes, Sure!" */
    ...
}

this.confirmService.confirm({
    message: 'Are you sure you want to exit?',
    header: 'Warning: Quit Application',
    icon: 'fa fa-exclamation-triangle',
    accept: () => { /* My accept actions */ },
    reject: () => { /* My reject actions */ },
    acceptVisible: this.notAllowedToLeave ? false : true,    /* No effect */
    acceptLabel: 'Yes, Sure!',      /* Giving Error:  'acceptLabel' does not exist in type 'Confirmation' */
    rejectLabel: 'No, I Don't!'     /* Giving Error:  'rejectLabel' does not exist in type 'Confirmation' */
});
```

Comment: I think you are overriding it by writing <p-footer> tag in template file, just remove <p-footer> tag from template and try to run.

Comment: Yes you were right. Its was getting overwritten. But as @splash says below, the PrimeNG version is another reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly specify it in HTML :

```
<p-confirmDialog acceptLabel="Yes, Sure!" rejectLabel="No, I Don't!"></p-confirmDialog>
```

See [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-umzf88)

Comment: Yes this was helpful. For my PrimeNG version I will go with yours solution.

Answer (score 2):

The properties `acceptLabel` and `rejectLabel` were not settable with `ConfirmationService` until PrimeNG 5.2.5: see https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/5090

You have to specifiy it in the HTML template if you must stick with version 4.1.1

https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng411-confirmation-test

Comment: Yeah! Its the version issue. But unfortunately I can't change the version due to project constraint rather I will go with your Second solution i.e. specifying the thing in HTML